# Java Iterating over and printing multiple arrays in order

Tags: java, arrays, loops, printing

I am attempting to print title, then name, then seat, but instead I get a very long list with the result I want followed with many nulls. What am I doing wrong here?

```
  for (int i = 0 ; i <15 ; i++) {
    System.out.println(title[i]);
    System.out.println(names[i]);
    System.out.println(seat[i]);  
}
```

I tried a while loop with a separate variable (titleCount, nameCount, seatCount) for each array as well. I incremented them all at the end of the loop, using them as indexes for the appropriate array. That didn't work either.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], and explain what behavior you expected and what *exactly* you observed.

Comment: Why are you using a hard-coded 15 value instead of the array's length property, if they ALL supposedly have the same length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you are getting nulls is because your are exceeding the amount of valid data in your arrays.

Assuming that the arrays has the same amount of data you can do something like

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < title.length ; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%s %s %s%n", title[i], names[i],seat[i]);  
}
```

This will print one rows for each set.

A better OO way to do this though is to create a class that represent this data and contains the Strings for `title` `name` and `seat` and then have an array (or ArrayList) of these Objects